# VueJs - Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "page". Expected DocumentPageDto, got Object

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component `PageViewer` with props defined like this

```
props: {
    page: DocumentPageDto,
  },
```

I use it in another Vue like as so

`<div><PageViewer :page="selectedPage"></PageViewer></div>`

`selectedPage` is set as a response from an API call which leads to this warning in the console

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "page". Expected
> DocumentPageDto, got Object

Which I understand, the response from the API is just a plain old `Object` I wonder if Vue has a way of dealing with this, I want to keep the prop type declaration as `DocumentPageDto` for intellisense.

Does Vue have a way of dealing with this, can I ignore the type check?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to ignore this type check, you must to use something like that: `props: ['page']`. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Comment: I could, then we lose intellisense :( but thank you

Comment: If you can determine it's type from the object itself (a property for example), you can use a [validator function](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation), otherwise, I'm not really sure.

Comment: In what way would you lose intellisense without this check?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights When you don't declare the prop type, intellisense on that class won't work any longer.

Comment: I've never had that issue when leaving out type checking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of declaring props like

```
props: {
   page: DocumentPageDto,
}
```

Use a property and apply the `@Prop` decorator from the [vue-property-decorator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-property-decorator) library works just fine.

```
@Prop()
diagram: DiagramDto = null;
```